# 30x Redirects and google page ranking

Tags: seo, redirects, drupal, drupal-6

I'm building a Drupal site where much of the content is going to be in static on specific pages. In Drupal, each piece of content (whether you like it or not) gets created its own page (node). To ensure that users do not view these nodes, I'm thinking about setting up a 30x redirect or a flat out 30x not found.

Will this method effect me negatively for google? Is there a different method that you could propose that may be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

30x redirects are not harmful when used in this way. In fact, 30x redirects are very common and have a lot of positive SEO uses in certain circumstances. In your case, if the redirect is taking the user to an equivilant page then it's a good thing as you making sure they get to the content thwy want. This won't have a direct affect on your SEO but won't reflect poorly on your site.

If you're going to report a page as not existing use a 404 Not Found or 410 Gone HTTP status code as they better represent a page not existing on your website.

Comment: I was almost thinking about just having google NOT crawl these pages, however, it can only help in the end if a visitor googles and finds that page (even tho it redirects) cause it can still attract traffic.